# How to manage existing custom objects with kubernetes go client?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-go-client

I'm writing a custom controller that would listen to a CR I defined and update/create other resources (ones defined by Istio). All the examples out there show either how to handle native resources or custom ones created in the same package. But the resources I want to manage already exist and are registered in the cluster. So what I'm failing to understand is how to create or update them in Go code without describng them with my own types.

Comment: In python this is pretty easy with CustomObjectsApi and loading yaml or json

Answer (score 0):

So I fgured out there is no way to do this without actually defining schemas for all the  objects I want to manage in my own code.
I suppose it would be a good idea for anyone providing open source CRDs to also provide a go library that defines the types for them